# C - how to check element next->next->value in linked lists (AVL-Tree)

Tags: c, linked-list, null, nodes, avl-tree

So I got a Task in my studies to write an AVL-Tree in C, and needed to implement Balance Function. 
now Basically where i'm getting stuck is when i need to check the child of the child of my element, which is not always initialized, the terminal then giving an error because well there's no child of the child, my question is if there's a way to define that if there's  that error just inserting zero?

I used another if Branch to check before if there's an child element but i find it  stupid.

```
            // if(node->left && node->right)  // check if tree have left and right
        // {
            if(node->left->height > node->right->height+1)
            {
                // if(node->left->left && node->left->right)
                // {
                    if(node->left->left->height < node->left->right->height)
                    {
                        AVL_rotate_left(avlt, node->left);
                    }
                // }
                AVL_rotate_right(avlt, node);
            }
```

Terminal:

```
Füge 12 ein...
Füge 2 ein...
Speicherzugriffsfehler   -// Memory access error
```

Comment: Why have you commented out the null-pointer checks? Those checks will protect you from attempting to dereference null pointers and possible crashes related to that.

Comment: There is not enough code in your question. All we can say here is: there is a bug in the code you didn't show. Please read this: [ask] and this: [mcve]

Comment: ".. which is not always initialized," - that would be the first problem to solve. Here is a simple, yet very descriptive, [gif showing rotation mechanics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_rotation#/media/File:Tree_Rotations.gif). you'll see that you couldn't care less whether a left.left or a right.right, etc. is null or not. All you care about is the height factors of the child nodes for the parent you're considering for a pivot are accurate (they had damn well better be), and differ by more than one. If they do, rotate toward the lesser side.

Comment: "...to check the child of the child of my element, which is not always initialized" That is __bad design__. It should _always_ be initialized and set to NULL when not in use. Change your implementation to always adhere to this requirement.